# Assigning attributes values to PointZM and convert to LineZM Geometries in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, z-value, m-values

I have elevation and measured values in attribute table of points layer.

Is there a way to convert this layer into PointZM (with elevation and measured) and assign elevation and measured values to PointZM geometry in QGIS/PostGIS?

How do I convert PointZM to lineZM geometry by preserving elevation and measured value of each vertex in lineZM in QGIS/PostGIS?

[image: Points attributes]

[image: First method]

[image: 2nd mehod]

Comment: are those points stored in PostGIS already or external and loaded into QGIS? do you want those lines stored in PostGIS? if you expect multiple individual lines as result, what's the identifying attribute?

Comment: Thanks ThingumaBob. Please see snapshot of attributes in original message above.Points are in shapefile. If possible I want output PointZM and LineZM in QGIS and PostGIS both and if not possible then in any one. Lines should be created based on road_code field and should have elevation and measured values in geometry..

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to get to your LINESTRINGZMs. Two of those are:

**ogr2ogr (not in QGIS)**
Since I find it most straight forward here, I suggest a one-step solution using *[ogr2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)*, hoping that you are familiar with the general idea of command line tools.
In the Terminal/Shell of your choice*, run:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=<your_host> port=<your_port> user=<user_with_create_rights> password=<your_password> dbname=<your_db_name>" "<path>/<to>/<shapefile>/<file_name>.shp" -nlt LINESTRINGZM -nln <new_table_name> -sql "SELECT road_code, MakeLine(MakePointZM(ST_X(GEOMETRY), ST_Y(GEOMETRY), elevation, distance)) AS geom FROM <file_name> GROUP BY road_code ORDER BY distance" -dialect sqlite
```

This will read the *shapefile* from disk, applies the `-sql` query on the *shapefile* data and imports the results (LINESTRINGZMs) into PostgreSQL/PostGIS (new table `<new_table_name>` with columns `road_code` and `wkb_geometry`).
This will connect the points by the `distance` attribute in ascending order, grouped by the `road_code` attribute.
Don´t forget to fill in all parts in `<>`. Note especially the use of `<file_name>` as name of your *shapefile* **and** name of the table to select from in the `-sql` statement.
Simply add that table to your QGIS project afterwards, e.g. via *Browser Panel*.
* *On Windows, the necessary* ogr2ogr.exe *comes shipped with your QGIS installation and can be found in the '/bin' folder; open a Terminal in that folder and run the command from there.*

***Virtual Layers* (in QGIS)**
Create a temporary *Virtual Layer* with similar SQL and results:

- *Layers* -> *Add Layer* -> *Add/Edit Virtual Layer*
- *Import* -> *choose point layer*
- *Query* -> `SELECT road_code, MakeLine(MakePointZM(ST_X(geometry), ST_Y(geometry), elevation, distance)) AS geometry FROM <local_name_of_layer> GROUP BY road_code ORDER BY distance`
- click *Test* to verify, and if all is good, *Ok* -> done

Import created layer into PostGIS via *Browser Panel* or *DB Manager*
or save to file.

Hope that helps; get back with any errors you encounter.

Comment: I tried to test first method and it gives error "unable to open datasource". It is my points.ship file (see snapshot in my original question). Second method create virtual layer and there are no lines drawn after saving in shp format in QGIS (see snapshot above). May be I am missing some thing. At first step, First, I want to create pointzm shapefile from my existing points.shp file and then to create linezm file.

Comment: @Mohsin to *ogr2ogr*: look at the spelling there is a space (`" C:\..."` -> `"C:\..."`)! to the *Virtual Layers*: my bad, you have to use the name 'geometry' instead of 'geom' in the query to refer to a geometry...I changed that in my answer.

Comment: @Mohsin ah, and to your request for having separate shapefiles for both types: I didn't get that from your question; do you actually want those results in PostGIS at all? use `SELECT id, Name, road_code, elevation, distance, MakePointZM(ST_X(geometry), ST_Y(geometry), elevation, distance) AS geometry FROM <name_of_layer>` as query in the *Virtual Layer* to simply convert your shape to POINTZMs. you can also use that query (change 'geometry' in `MakePointZM(...)` to 'GEOMETRY') in *ogr2ogr*.

Comment: Hi ThingnumaBob, thanks for your support. First method now works fine but when I add created layer from PostGIS then there are no any feature drawn and attribute table is also empty. Second method also works fine but no output features and when I open its attribute table attributes are there. Yeah I want output results in PostGIS and to view them in QGIS.

Comment: (Again my scenario: I have simple points shapefile with elevation, measured and other attributes values. First I want to convert this points file to PointZm so its geometry should have elevation and measured value should preserve my attributes also. Then to convert points or Pointzm file to LineZM so this LineZM should have elevation and measured value at each vertex or node. Hopefully you got it). If you say and need further clarification then I can add snapshots.

Comment: Can you check why scripts are not working properly? I tried by changing parameters but not successful. May be I am missing some thing. Looking for support from you or any other genius.

Comment: I will be happy if any one else can help in this regard.